# Plotting mixed models in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, lme4, mixed-models

I constructed a mixed model and now using `sjp.lmer`, I am plotting predicted values against each of my predictor. The name of the fitted model is `mdl.lmer` and the `names.vec` is the vector of names of the predictor.I want to do a loop like this such that the all plots are present in a single pdf

```
pdf("my.pdf")
for(i in seq_along(names.vec)){

    clim <- names.vec[i]
    sjp.lmer(mdl.lmer, type = "pred.fe", vars = clim, show.scatter = T)
    ggsave(plot = last_plot())
}
```

The issue is that sjp.lmer line makes a plot but I am not able to assign it to an object and then print the object to an open device. Usually I do this:

```
pdf("my.pdf")
for(i in seq_along(names.vec)){

  clim <- names.vec[i]

  p <- ggplot(dat, aes(x = clim, y = response)) + geom_line()
  print(p)
}
```

And this command saves all the plots in an open pdf. However, I am not able to achieve this for the mixed model case.